# How to create a script so that users can test PHP when inputting!

Tags: php, testing

How do i create a script with a form, and then when the user inputs php code it is being tested? Basically creating an PHP ONLINE TESTER script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tester means.... what exactly?  Are you attempting to check it for syntax?  Or run the code given?

Comment: an example, like this website: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to clean the input, use `eval()`, and send the output. I think the first thing to remove would be `eval()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

So basically i would just do like this:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="get" action="">
  <p>
    <textarea name="code" cols="50" rows="15" id="code"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Execute!" />
  </p>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_GET['Submit']))
{
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    eval($code);
}
?>
```

But this isn't totally secure i guess? What should i consider securing?